# htaccess rewrite allcaps.html to lowercase.html

Tags: html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been trying to figure out how to get this to work for awhile now and it's not making any sense to me. What I've put together so far forces it to reference the lowercase.html file from /BLAH to /blah.html but I can't seem to put together /BLAH.html to /blah.html.

This is only to move SomeCapS.html (or .HTML I guess) to somecaps.html instead.

Any ideas on how to fix this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/rewrite-uppercase-lowercase.html 
# If there are caps, set HASCAPS to true and skip next rule
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [E=HASCAPS:TRUE,S=1]

# Skip this entire section if no uppercase letters in requested URL 

RewriteRule ![A-Z] - [S=28]

# Replace single occurance of CAP with cap, then process next Rule.
RewriteRule ^([^A]*)A(.*)$ $1a$2
RewriteRule ^([^B]*)B(.*)$ $1b$2
RewriteRule ^([^C]*)C(.*)$ $1c$2
RewriteRule ^([^D]*)D(.*)$ $1d$2
RewriteRule ^([^E]*)E(.*)$ $1e$2
RewriteRule ^([^F]*)F(.*)$ $1f$2
RewriteRule ^([^G]*)G(.*)$ $1g$2
RewriteRule ^([^H]*)H(.*)$ $1h$2
RewriteRule ^([^I]*)I(.*)$ $1i$2
RewriteRule ^([^J]*)J(.*)$ $1j$2
RewriteRule ^([^K]*)K(.*)$ $1k$2
RewriteRule ^([^L]*)L(.*)$ $1l$2
RewriteRule ^([^M]*)M(.*)$ $1m$2
RewriteRule ^([^N]*)N(.*)$ $1n$2
RewriteRule ^([^O]*)O(.*)$ $1o$2
RewriteRule ^([^P]*)P(.*)$ $1p$2
RewriteRule ^([^Q]*)Q(.*)$ $1q$2
RewriteRule ^([^R]*)R(.*)$ $1r$2
RewriteRule ^([^S]*)S(.*)$ $1s$2
RewriteRule ^([^T]*)T(.*)$ $1t$2
RewriteRule ^([^U]*)U(.*)$ $1u$2
RewriteRule ^([^V]*)V(.*)$ $1v$2
RewriteRule ^([^W]*)W(.*)$ $1w$2
RewriteRule ^([^X]*)X(.*)$ $1x$2
RewriteRule ^([^Y]*)Y(.*)$ $1y$2
RewriteRule ^([^Z]*)Z(.*)$ $1z$2

# If there are any uppercase letters, restart at very first RewriteRule in file.
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [N]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HASCAPS} TRUE
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.html
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you have access to your vhost/server config?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it's a shared host running cPanel so I just have access to the .htaccess file which is why I had to use the rather lame looking de-capper above :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the built in rewrite map directive, because this has a lot of problems. First, the number of internal redirects is capped at something like 10. This means you can only redirect internally 10 times, and a URI with 11 upper case letters will cause too many internal redirects, resulting in a 500 server error.

The [Apache documentation has a page for RewriteMaps](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/rewritemap.html).

But the problem is rewrite maps *must* be declared in the vhost/server config. And not in the htaccess file. If you don't have access, you may need to write a script to do this for you. Something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule [A-Z] /tolower.php [L]
```

And in the `tolower.php` you'd need to look at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, then change all the letters to lower case, then either redirect the browser to the new URL without any upper case letters or, internally load that page and return it on the browser's behalf.

Comment: Hm, so there's nothing that can be added to the .htaccess? I just tested out a page with something like 24 caps for the URL and it redirected it fine. I'm guessing its because I don't have [R] anywhere in the file to signify the redirect, but I don't really see myself using any file names longer than 10 characters really.

Also, I'm going to be attempting to move this to a completely static host in the near future (getforge.com if it matters) and I'm not sure if the php alternative would work there (htaccess still seems to).

Comment: @Salo hmm, you're right. Tested it locally and it's not affected by the internal recursion limit.